# How to avoid changing the Excel connection string for SSAS Role

Tags: excel, ssas, business-intelligence, olap, cube

I have implemented the Dynamic Security in our BI-SSAS Projekt using a User-Dimension that is updated from Active Directory. I created SSAS-Roles and inside I restrict the users to see only the specified branches.
As Front-End they are using Excel. The problem is that Excel does not use as default the SSAS-Role created so I need to modify the conection string and add the following Property:`Extended Properties="Role=PowerUsers"` . 
How can we use the role created without having to edit the conection string from excel ? Could be this Excel connection string property added as default?

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't Excel use the right role if you remove Roles= from the connection string? Is the user in question an SSAS admin? Are you 100% sure? If you connect Profiler to SSAS and watch while that user connects it should list the roles the user belongs to. If the roles say *,PowerUsers,Readers then the asterisk means the user is an admin.

Comment: @GregGalloway Hi...I will also try with a Profiler, but I can tell you that if a User open a new Excel file and connect to our SSAS Cube then he can see all the branches. If I use this property in the connection string then he is restricted.

Comment: you might also install BIDS Helper and run the Roles Report on your cube. It will expand the security groups in case that user is in a group you weren't aware of. https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roles%20Report&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @GregGalloway Hi, Greg! I put a Profile on Analysis and as you already presumed, the initialiyation is made with  *,powerusers

Comment: I would run the BIDS Helper roles report and also check the server level SSAS admins. That user is an admin. If you remove him as an admin you won't need to specify Roles on the connection string.

Comment: @GregGalloway that's right! I made a check with my user and that did the trick... The user was SSAS Admin. Can you write the answer down so I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't Excel use the right role if you remove Roles= from the connection string? Is the user in question an SSAS admin? Are you 100% sure? If you connect Profiler to SSAS and watch while that user connects it should list the roles the user belongs to. If the roles say *,PowerUsers,Readers then the asterisk means the user is an admin. If you remove him as an admin you won't need to specify Roles on the connection string.

You might also install BIDS Helper and run the [Roles Report](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/RolesReport/) on your cube. It will expand the security groups in case that user is in a group you weren't aware of.

Answer (score 0):

There is not directly way in the standalone Excel pivot table, but there are a couple of potential approaches you can try:
1) Save the connection string (file) in a shared folder where your users can access it all, you don't have to modify anything in Excel once you specify that file(folder), but you still have to modify that file in the folder. (not good but should be okay)
2) 'IF' you are using SharePoint excel service, the thing is simple: just create a SSS, all can be managed under SharePoint SSS